# Python - Pull Out Values from Only Dictionaries that Meet a Certain Criteria

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a Python list called "results" that has dictionaries as its values:

```py
results = [
{
 'postingStatus': 'Active', 
 'postEndDate': '1601683199000', 
 'boardId': '_internal', 
 'postStartDate': '1591084714000)'
 }, 
{
 'postingStatus': 'Expired', 
 'postEndDate': '1601683199000', 
 'boardId': '_external', 
 'postStartDate': '1591084719000)'
}
]
```

How would I create a list that gets all the values from the dictionary where the 'boardID' value is '_internal' (but ignores the dictionary where 'boardID' is '_external')? As an end result, I'm hoping for a list with the following contents:

```
['Active','1601683199000','_internal','1591084714000']
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I spent a couple hours attempting to solve this issue, but came up short and with 12 lines of ugly code that didn't work. Not sure it was worth posting, esp when it seems advanced python coders could accomplish this in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension:

```py
out = [v for d in results for v in d.values() if d["boardId"] == "_internal"]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['Active', '1601683199000', '_internal', '1591084714000)']
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! It turns out that my code would be more readable if I pulled out the full dictionary itself, rather than pulling the values into a list. Can I use a similar list comprehension approach so that I pull out the following dictionary: {
 'postingStatus': 'Active', 
 'postEndDate': '1601683199000', 
 'boardId': '_internal', 
 'postStartDate': '1591084714000)'
 }

Comment: @slimPickens142 You can use `filtered = [d for d in results if d["boardId"] == "_internal"]`

Answer (score 0):

without using List-comprehension

```
for items in results:
    if items['boardId'] == '_internal':
        lst1 = list(items.values())

print(lst1)
```